# SelectionChanged not firing WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating a chess game using WPF. I need to get the indices of the selected cell (row / column).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name ="chessGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          HeadersVisibility="None"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          CurrentCellChanged="chessGrid_CurrentCellChanged"
          SelectionChanged="chessGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[0]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[1]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[2]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[3]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[4]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[5]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[6]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[7]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[8]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding columns[9]}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

When a cell has changed i call:

```
private void chessGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    x = chessGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    Debug.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Which allows me to get the column index of the cell.

And i currently try:

```
private void chessGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    y = chessGrid.SelectedIndex;
    Debug.WriteLine(y);
}
```

to get the row. But this does not work, when removing SelectionUnit="Cell" the above works, but i cannot do that of course since you should not be able to select a whole row. I also tried:

```
private void chessGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    x = chessGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    y = chessGrid.Items.IndexOf(chessGrid.CurrentCell)
    Debug.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Which sets y to -1?

So my question is how do i get the row / column - index of a selected cell using simple WPF and datagrid?

EDIT: A requirement is that the application should use the three layer architecture.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Read about binding and MVVM.

Comment: @KostyaK I forgot to mention that the application has to be written using three layer architecture and i think MVVM is not compatible with that but ill read up on it, thanks.

Comment: @Tagor If you mean separate data access, business logic, and presentation layers, use MVVM. It’s painful and difficult to use WPF any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void dggg_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = chessGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    y = chessGrid.Items.IndexOf(chessGrid.CurrentCell.Item);
}
```